# How to use encoding utf-8.py instead of cp1252.py in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have written a very small program that copies all lines of one file to another file - when the line contains a certain string. Here is the complete source:

```
f_in = open("all.txt", "r")
f_out = open("all.out", "w")

for line in f_in:
    if "<title>" in line:
        f_out.write(line)

f_out.close()
f_in.close()
```

That works very well, until it comes to an utf-8 character in all.txt. Then it fails saying:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 7102: character map to <undefined>

Now I did a BAD workaround: In the directory \Python\Lib\encodings I have copied utf-8.py and renamed it to cp1252.py.

From now on - the little program above runs with no problem. But there must be a more elegant solution. Can you tell me what is needed to make Phyton use utf-8.py instead of cp1252.py?

**I am sure this is possible with no heavy conversion and decoding and whatever - just tell Python to use another decoding instead of cp1252.py.**

Comment: How about you start with the [Unicode howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)?

Comment: Your bad workaround just saved my sanity after spending hours trying to get AWS Command-Line-Interface (which is written in Python) to export some data that included non-ASCII characters :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`io.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to read and write Unicode values instead:

```
import io

with io.open('all.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f_in:
    with io.open('all.out', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            if u"<title>" in line:
                f_out.write(line)
```

Renaming codec files is the last thing you should do.

Comment: >Renaming codec files is the last thing you should do.

I know - that's why I have asked! ;-) Thank you - your solution works perfectly and very fast.

Comment: If Python 2 compatibility isn't needed, `open(f, 'r', encoding='utf8')` works as well.

Comment: @Cees: `open()` in Python 3 is the exact same function as `io.open()`.

Answer (score 6):

Run python with the `-X utf8` option.

I had the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0141' in position 10: character maps to <undefined>
```

And I used `with open(filepath, "r+", encoding="utf-8") as yaml_file:` (explicit encoding), as one would expect, but windows was being poopy and kept using `cp1252.py`, which was driving me up the wall because it kept causing the error above.

Anyway, running `python -X utf8 .\script.py` fixed my woes.

Comment: I had this exact issue when running a gitlab runner under windows: it couldn't print emojis. With the flag you proposed, it runs flawlessly. This is probably the wrong question for this answer, but this answer helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I posted it here, as I found this question via google when searching for the error posted. It makes sense to post the answer in the first result of the search (even if it's not entirely related to OP's question).