# tqdm and pytest INTERNALERROR> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 245-254: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, tqdm

MRE:

`test_test.py`:

```
import main

def test_file() -> None:
    main.main("qfqsdfsqdds")
    assert True
```

`main.py`:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

def main(username: str):
    for i in tqdm(range(10)):
        a = i + 1
```

Running the test through `PyCharm` raises the following error:

```
test_test.py::test_file PASSED                                           [100%]
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 270, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 324, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py", line 349, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 112, in pytest_runtest_protocol
INTERNALERROR>     runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 131, in runtestprotocol
INTERNALERROR>     reports.append(call_and_report(item, "call", log))
INTERNALERROR>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py", line 224, in call_and_report
INTERNALERROR>     hook.pytest_runtest_logreport(report=report)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pluggy\_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\pytest_plugin.py", line 300, in pytest_runtest_logreport
INTERNALERROR>     self.report_test_output(report, test_id)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\pytest_plugin.py", line 208, in report_test_output
INTERNALERROR>     dump_test_stderr(self.teamcity, test_id, test_id, data)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\common.py", line 78, in dump_test_stderr
INTERNALERROR>     messages.testStdErr(test_id, chunk, flowId=flow_id)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\messages.py", line 190, in testStdErr
INTERNALERROR>     self.message('testStdErr', name=testName, out=out, flowId=flowId)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_runner_tools.py", line 117, in message
INTERNALERROR>     _old_service_messages.message(self, messageName, **properties)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\messages.py", line 101, in message
INTERNALERROR>     retry_on_EAGAIN(self.output.write)(self.encode(message))
INTERNALERROR>                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\messages.py", line 68, in encode
INTERNALERROR>     value = value.encode(self.encoding)
INTERNALERROR>             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
INTERNALERROR>     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
INTERNALERROR>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
INTERNALERROR> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 245-254: character maps to <undefined>

============================== 1 passed in 0.02s ==============================

Process finished with exit code 3
```

Running `pytest` with the terminal works though.

The problem does seem to come from `tqdm`.

I'm using `Python 3.11.1` and:

```
PyCharm 2022.3.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-223.8214.51, built on December 20, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.23 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2030M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    me.lensvol.blackconnect (0.5.0)
    com.chesterccw.excelreader (2022.12.1-203.223)
    com.github.copilot (1.1.38.2229)
```

As @aaron pointed out, there might be a huge error on the stack trace from PyCharm because when I click on About it does show `2022.3.1` and when I run the code the stack trace says `2022.1.3`.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the PyCharm pytest plugin - maybe file a bug report with JetBrains.

Comment: Note: I couldn't reproduce this on macOS with Python 3.11.1 and PyCharm 2022.3.1 CE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using the `cp1252.py`-encoding which works until it finds a sequence it can't make sense of with this encoding (as you pointed out probably related to tqdm). The encoding is related to Windows, so it makes sense that it couldn't be reproduced by aaron (macOS) and me (Linux).

If you can give it parameters to the execution of python, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71812796/15219428) could be helpful. The idea is to force it to use utf-8 encodings with the argument `-X utf8`. You can add that argument under `Interpreter Options` in `Run -> Edit Configurations...` for your py-test.

[image: Debug Configurations]

---

It seems that it just takes the [default encoding in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/670197/finding-out-the-default-character-encoding-in-windows), you can check if this is indeed the case on your system in the PowerShell:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default
```

---

There are multiple issues on the github-page of this plugin, [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-messages/issues/192#issuecomment-422077875) workaround looks worth a try to me:

"Just add the following line into the beginning of all files with tests:"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

---

Maybe you can try [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/encoding.html#console) too, but I think it's only for the console output and does not overwrite the default for the plugins too.

1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), select Editor | General | Console.
2. Select the default encoding from the Default Encoding list. (change it to utf-8)
3. Click OK to apply the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, after adding `-X utf8`, it still doesn't work (the traceback in the same so I think it didn't understand it and still uses cp1252: https://i.imgur.com/UhxPTkX.png)

Comment: I added some more options, hope those work for you!

Comment: Those are only workarounds, I agree with @MrBean, that there is probably a bug in the plugin. In fact, they already did a [bugfix](https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-messages/issues/260) a year ago that is supposed to escape unencodable messages. I suppose this character from tqdm slipped through the cracks and the escaping of the character failed.

Comment: Changing PyCharm encoding settings did work.